# CSV download box not appearing in rails 2.3.11

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to export a csv file with some data. I am making an ajax call after selecting some of the rows from the view table (jqGrid) and exporting it in a csv format. The issue is after successful ajax call, the filtered data is appearing as an alert message not as a download option?? any ideas??

View Code:

```
 function x() {

 var obj = jQuery("input:checked").map(function() { return jQuery(this).parents('tr').attr('id'); });

 var arr = jQuery.makeArray(obj);
 var data = arr.join(',');


 $.ajax({
     url : '<%= url_for :action => "export_to_csv" %>',
     type : 'POST',
     data : {data:data},
     dataType : 'json',
         success : function(response) {
           alert("Details saved successfully!!!");
         },
         error : function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }       
    });     


      }
```

controller code:

```
def export_to_csv
 require 'fastercsv'

 data = params['data'].split(',')
 @gos = GoSe.find(:all, :conditions => [ "id IN (?)", data])
 csv = FasterCSV.generate do |line|
 cols = ["ID","Details","PartnerCode","Sece","Date","Partner","Person","TaxName","TaxID"]
 line << cols
 @gos.each do |entry|                
 line << [entry.id, entry.description, entry.code, entry.ellipsis, entry.oDate, entry.name, entry.people_name, entry.tax_name, entry.tax_id ]
     end  
  end

send_data(csv, 
:type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present', 
:disposition => "attachment; filename=go_data_#{Time.now.strftime('%d-%m-%y--%H-%M')}.csv") 

end
```

Comment: The javascript doesn't have access to the file system (unless you use the new filewriter api which isn't widely supported) so you'll never get prompted for a file download with code like this - you need to be making a normal, non ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following update in the code..its working..Try it out!!

```
function x() {

var obj = jQuery("input:checked").map(function() { return jQuery(this).parents('tr').attr('id'); });

var myAjaxVariable = null;
var arr = jQuery.makeArray(obj);
var data = arr.join(',');


$.ajax({
 url : '<%= url_for :action => "export_to_csv" %>',
 type : 'POST',
 data : {data:data},
 dataType : 'json',
 async : false,
     success : function(response) {myAjaxVariable = response;},
     error : function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }       
  });   

window.open( "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(myAjaxVariable))  


}
```

Comment: What Frederick mentioned above is correct. Its not possible to get a download pop up with ajax request to be more specific with asynchronous request. So we need to make it synchronous using async:false option and then saving all in one variable(global) and then calling a window open option. I am sure there are other methods but this one worked for me. Moreover i am skeptical of its working in IE. this you can check!!